# Javascript just can hide button at the first row

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide my update button when input lock is checked, but the button update that success hidden is only on the first row of data and for data on other row the button update isn't hide eventhough user click input lock. So what's wrong with my code?

this is my datatable code:

```
var datatable = $('.datatable-employee').DataTable({
      "bDestroy" : true,
      "ajax" : {
        "url" : '/employee/payroll/getpayrollemployee',
        "type" : "POST",
        "data": { "periode": periode }
      },
      "columns" : [
        {
          className: "text-left",
          data: "employee"
        },
        {
          className: "text-right",
          data: "salary"
        },
        {
          className: "text-center",
          render : function (data, type, row) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input-styled lock" name="lock" value="" data-id="'+row.id+'" aria-expanded="false" />';
          }
        },
        { className: "text-center",
          render : function (data, type, row) {
            return '\
            <div class="list-icons">\
              <div class="dropdown">\
                <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-menu9"></i></a>\
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">\
                  <a href="'+row.actiondetail+'" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-search4"></i> Detail</a>\
                  <a href="'+row.actionupdate+'" class="dropdown-item" id="checkupdate"><i class="icon-pencil3"></i> Update</a>\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </div>';
          }
        },
      ]
    });
```

and this is my code to updated:

```
var _lockUpdateData = function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".lock", function() {
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#checkupdate').hide();
      } else {
        $('#checkupdate').show();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is more than one checkupdate. You cannot have duplicate IDs. Instead use a class and navigate the DOM

Assuming the lock is in the same container as the checkupdate, then try this.

Note the `!this.checked`.

```
$(document).on('click', ".lock", function() {
   $(this).closest("common ancestor selector here")
    .find(".checkupdate").toggle(!this.checked);
});
```